# Clickable edges on graph d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a possibility to make edges clickable? (In order to show more information about the edges)
![Graph][1]

Comment: Just add `.on("click", function() { ... })` when adding the edges.

Comment: But you might want to also make your lines a little wider, to give more room for a click...

Comment: You mean the lines which connect the nodes together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your lines:

```
//...
.append("line")
//...
```

just add an on click listener like this:

```
//...
.append("line")
.on("click", function(){
  // code to run on click
 })
 //...
```